# Отобразить компоненты по клику (нестандартная задача)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
  <div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4" >
        <nav>
          <ul v-for="(index, i) in navBar" :key="index" >
            <li>
              {{ navBar[i] }}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <TaskFormComponent ref="taskForm"/>
        <TaskActionComponent ref="taskColor"/>
        <button @click="openTask">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  data(){
    return{
      navBar:[
        "Форма",
        "Цвет",
        "Детали",
      ]
    }
 }
```

Подскажите как я бы могла сделать следующее -> Чтобы при клике на кнопку"некст", отображались компоненты по типу this.$refs.taskForm.show = true,и то есть к примеру для нулевого индекса был привязана именно тот компонент. Допустим есть элемент "форма" и я к ней приписывала класс "Active" через v-bind:class, нажимая на кнопку некст я бы хотела чтобы active переходила на [1] индекс массива и открывался следующий компонент this.$refs.taskAction.show = true. Логика довольно таки глупа и я бы могла v-if использовать с разными значениями, но нужно именно так (
Если кратко, то по клику на кнопку "Next" должны отображаться разными компоненты и должен динамически появляться класс active для нужно элемента массива. По дефолту [0]

Answer (score 0):

```
<li v-bind:class="{active: activeBar==i}">
    {{ navBar[i] }}
</li>

data(){
    return{
        navBar:[
            "Форма",
            "Цвет",
            "Детали",
        ],
        activeBar:0
    }
},
methods: {
    openTask: function () {
        this.activeBar = (this.activeBar + 1) % this.navBar.length;
    }
}
```